# Need to know how to use heroku's Ephemeral filesystem and write file to /tmp folder

Tags: heroku, python-2.7

I am new to heroku.I have deployed my app to heroku which has python script running on clock
process.In that script I need to write to xml file using heroku's Ephemeral filesystem in /tmp folder and I would need url for that file so that I can use this url to do some other processing which reads data from this file.

Answer (score 2):

On Heroku, you cannot make a file in `/tmp` publicly accessible. The only way to have the contents of that file accessible via `http` would be to transfer that file to somewhere else, such as Amazon S3, or `scp` it to some other server.

Think about it: say you have 10 dynos running, and somebody makes a request that causes a new file `newFile` to be created in `/tmp`. Well, it's in `/tmp` on only one of your dynos. If the next request the load balancer directs you to a different dyno, then that file is nonexistent. Moreover, the dyno that you just created `newFile` on may not even exist 5 seconds later! Heroku spins dynos up and down all the time.

HTTP is a [Stateless Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Examples). If you are to design your system properly, you should treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks Travis really appreciate your quick response,as per my understanding for my script which runs on clock process only one dyno will be running right?so in same script Can I write xml file in temp folder,once I close that file in same script I need to provide that xml file url to twilio's outgoing call request wich need http url?